# section can't be divided into columns

Tags: sections-paragraphs

I want to format my page into two columns, other paragraph command work fine except the first paragraph command after section tags. It remains as one column format. I wonder why . \paragraph{sources: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wireless_network_configuration. } is the tag that i have trouble bit. if you can, i need some feedback for my latex structure.

this following code is my tex file.

```
\documentclass[14pt,twoside,a4papaer,twocolumn]{article}
\pagestyle{plain}
\author{An Pham}
\title{Wireless Configuration Setting }

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\paragraph{sources: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wireless\_network\_configuration. }

\paragraph{The following guide is meant to clarify to process to configure the wireless interfaces as well as activating it. This is also being part of GNU Free Documentation License.}

\paragraph{According to wiki.archlinux.ord, wirless netowrk configuration can be broken into 4 parts which are activating interfaces, discovering access points, connetcing with wireless interface, and ip configuration. The first three stages are mostly need the manual configuration, and the final stage can be executated automatically by the system.
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.se! `\paragraph{...}` is intended for inline titles in document. do you really need so long titles? where is than text of document? `sources: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wireless\_network\_configuration.` can not be broken into more lines. for this you need write it as link: `sources: \url{https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wireless\_network\_configuration.}` ...

Comment: turn out i got the wrong format. I fixed it, the title is an actual text itselves. But i still have problem with url . I recevie this error.(./Wireless network configuration.aux)
! Undefined control sequence.
l.11 Sources:\url
                 {https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wireless\_network\_co...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is extended comment:

the best what i can do and obtain from your *mwe* is:

[image]

for `\url` you need to add `hyperref` or `url` package in preamble of your document:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4papaer,twocolumn]{article}% 14pt font size is not defined!
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\author{An Pham}
\title{Wireless Configuration Setting }

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\pagestyle{plain}

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[11]
\paragraph{sources: \url{https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wireless\_network\_configuration} }
\lipsum[11]

\paragraph{The following guide is meant to clarify to process to configure the wireless interfaces as well as activating it. This is also being part of GNU Free Documentation License.}
\lipsum[11]

\paragraph{According to wiki.archlinux.ord, wirless netowrk configuration can be broken into 4 parts which are activating interfaces, discovering access points, connetcing with wireless interface, and ip configuration. The first three stages are mostly need the manual configuration, and the final stage can be executated automatically by the system.
}
\lipsum[11]

\end{document}
```

note: package `lipsum` is only for generating dummy text. i suggest you that you reconsider to have such paragraphs titles. it is very strange ...

Comment: I definitely do that, thanks. I also learn about lipsom package. that helps a lot when i test my format.

Comment: i still can't format link right. xdvi command display this. Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-helvetica-medium-r-*-*-12-*-*-*-*-*-*" to type FontStruct

Comment: for help you you should edit your question and add to your *mwe* packages which you use beside provided in it. code example in my answer works without problems. i use `sumatra` for pdf viewer.

Comment: zarko, I found out the solution. The truth is the url link can't be broken to wrap by column division. In order to do so, i have to use breakurl package. what's mwe?  sorry i only can export a dvi file. I can't post as png.

Comment: check you latex installation. it seems that it is not recent ... upgrade it! as far as remember, `breakurl` is obsolete. `hypperref` works for sure. proof: see image in my answer.